# Cryptic Angular 2 error on a clean setup

Tags: angular

I've created an ASP.NET WebApi2 project with Angular 2 beta 15. The project works completely fine on my system but when my collagues get it from the source control they are all getting this error while loading main app (it stays on "Loading" message of the `<app>Loading</app>`). I couldn't figure out what's missing on their end and I'd appreciate any help.

```
EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Call stack:
angular2.dev.js:23925 Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at resolvePromise (angular2-polyfills.js:602)
    at angular2-polyfills.js:638
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:423)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (angular2.dev.js:2118)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:422)
    at Zone.runTask (angular2-polyfills.js:320)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (angular2-polyfills.js:541)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:493)BrowserDomAdapter.logError 
@ angular2.dev.js:23925ExceptionHandler.call 
@ angular2.dev.js:1323(anonymous function) 
@ angular2.dev.js:12857schedulerFn 
@ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub 
@ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next 
@ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next 
@ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next 
@ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext 
@ Rx.js:11191Subject._next 
@ Rx.js:11183Subject.next 
@ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit 
@ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError 
@ angular2.dev.js:13666NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError 
@ angular2.dev.js:2143ZoneDelegate.handleError 
@ angular2-polyfills.js:394Zone.runGuarded 
@ angular2-polyfills.js:300drainMicroTaskQueue 
@ angular2-polyfills.js:554ZoneTask.invoke 
@ angular2-polyfills.js:493
```

The IIS setup, folder structure, browser versions are all same. There are no errors in any of the requests, all of them are 200 OK.

I tried to debug but got lost in the bowels of Angular. I'm guessing we need to install something else on their computers but I don't know what..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was VS.NET Update 1. Every computer with U1 has this problem. Installing Update 2 solved it. Still don't know why though..